# How to get the following while loop to work

Tags: php

I have the following code and it seems to be working if I don't use the while loop but for some reason, echo something out on the screen if I do use the while loop. I thought that I would need the while loop if I were to go through the whole record such as finding more than one user who has more than this particular number of points? Most of the time, it had been working for me with the while loop but not for this problem....

```
<?php
ob_start();
include_once __DIR__.'/header2.php';
if(!isset($_SESSION['u_uid'])) {
   echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=index.php?level3promo=notlogin'>";
    exit();
} else {
    if($_SESSION['u_permission'] == 0) {
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=header2.php?level3promo=nopermission'>";
        exit();
    } else {
    include_once __DIR__. '/includes/dbh.php';

   $category = strip_tags($_POST['category']); 
   $csrf = strip_tags($_POST['csrf']);



   if(!isset($_SESSION['key'])) {
     echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=header2.php?level3promo=notset'>";
        exit();
       } else {

       if($csrf !== $_SESSION['key']) {

           echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=header2.php?level3promo=errorwithform'>";
                                         exit();
                                            } else {
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM level3promo WHERE id = ?;";

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
     //Prepare the prepared statement
     if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        echo 'SQL statement failed';
     } else {
     //Bind parameters to the placeholder
     mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $category);
      //Run parameters inside database
     mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
     $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
     $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

     if ($resultCheck < 1) {

         echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=header2.php?level3promo=nocategories
         exit();'>";
     } else {
       $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);



    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM rewards WHERE reward_points >= ?;";

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
     //Prepare the prepared statement
     if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql2)) {
        echo 'SQL statement failed';
     } else {
     //Bind parameters to the placeholder
     mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $row['points']);
      //Run parameters inside database
     mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
     $result2 = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
      $resultCheck2 = mysqli_num_rows($result2);


       echo '<table class="admin_level3promo">

           <tr>
           <th colspan="2" class="update_title">Welcome to the Administrator\'s Level 3 Promo Qualified Users\' Section</th>
           </tr>';



      if ($resultCheck2 < 1) {

      echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=header2.php?level3promo=lackofpoints'>";
      exit();
     } else {


         $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM memberships WHERE user_uid = ? AND subscriptionplan3 IS NULL;";

         $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
     //Prepare the prepared statement
     if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql3)) {
        echo 'SQL statement failed';
     } else {

     //Bind parameters to the placeholder
     mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $row2['user_uid']);
      //Run parameters inside database
     mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
     $result3 = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
     $resultCheck3 = mysqli_num_rows($result3);


     if ($resultCheck3 < 1) {
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=header2.php?level3promo=lackofrecords'>";
      exit(); 
     } else {







           echo '<tr>
                      <th>Result No:</th><td>',htmlspecialchars($rowCounter),'</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                      <th>ID:</th><td>',htmlspecialchars($row2['id']),'</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                      <th>Username:</th><td>',htmlspecialchars($row2['user_uid']),'</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                      <th>E-Mail:</th><td>',htmlspecialchars($row2['user_email']),'</td>
                      </tr>';



     }

     echo '</table>';


     $rowCounter = 0;




     $rowCounter++;


       }
     }
     }
    }
}
}
}
}
}
}
ob_end_flush();
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <title></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

</body>
```

I have included a couple of pictures of my databased:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Bngk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q25NY.png)

As can been seen in both tables, only musician888 should have more than 5000 points but I can only get this to work without the while loop

I thought that for this situation, i should be using the while loop

Comment: I tried to use a while loop for the $row2 variables but it is echoing something on the screen but I never used echo

Comment: Is it because I am only just displaying one result as in one possible winner?

Comment: May I ask where the while-loop is? I don't see any?

Comment: I left out the while loop because this is the working code but if I added it in, it doesn't work. I placed the while loop at the same sport as the $row2

Comment: How am I/are we supposed to help you if you don't show us your while-loop? Can you show us your while loop?

Comment: if I add the while loop, it says there are no records but in fact, there is a record

Comment: It just seems that the is null part is not working

Comment: it was my row counter

Comment: It should have been at the top but I thought that all error messages should have been displayed on the screen without adding the following:

Comment: ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: this is strange... the problem is somewhere with my $resultCheck3

Comment: there should be one value with null but it seems that it is not detecting it

Comment: There are a few problems in that code. Your `$rowCounter` variable is set to zero immediately before it is incremented, and that's after you have used it in your display, for example.

The whole reason for your `$sql3` query (run inside the loop for the results of `$sql2`) seems to be to see if the member has a current membership, which could be done in a single query to replace `$sql2`, which in turn would make the whole thing easier to read.

Comment: I thought you should set the counter to 0 first before incrementing it?

Comment: when I echo $resultCheck3, I get the value of 10

Comment: Could I make a suggestion... Your code would be much easier to read and troubleshoot if it weren’t buried in nested `if(){}else{}` blocks. When you’re testing for an error, you don’t need an else; just throw an exception, exit, or redirect; the script won’t continue if you tell it to stop.  Example: `if(!isset($_SESSION[‘u_uid’])) { header(‘location: /index.php?level3promo=notlogin’); die(); }  if($_SESSION[‘u_permission’]==0){header(‘location: header2.php?level3promo=nopermission’); die(); }   include...`  This improves readability because you don’t have to keep it all in your head.

Comment: Second suggestion, get all your information together before you output anything (output buffering is rarely needed).  This allows you to send headers at any point in the logic. It also allows you to focus on one thing at a time.   You’re really close on this one...  The reason I mention it is because it would allow you to show just the part that isn’t working, and you’d get a lot more help that way (if you didn’t figure it out on your own already)

Comment: I have got it working but in theory, should I use as little while loop as possible? I got it to work by adding only one while loop at the end...

Comment: Nothing magical about a while loop; it just goes through all the results your database gives you. If you have to make queries inside a loop, just make sure your inside query isn’t clobbering the outside loop. Or better yet, make a better query.   I don’t know what while loop you’re talking about— I’m reading this on a phone, and there’s too much stuff to sift through. Is the while loop even in your post?